# Scrolling through a bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a large bucket on AWS.  The program I'm using EVS requires that all videos and photos must be inone bucket instead of creating new buckets.

So my bucket now has a crapload of stuff in there.   Is there a way that I can just skip to the item I want in the bucket without having to scroll through the entire bucket.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the AWS web console, you can just start typing and it will filter the files in the bucket.